# My visual studio stops working when opening files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2015 community. But it stops working as I try opening files(.h or .cpp) in a project. However, it can build projects as long as I do not open any file.

I have uninstalled and installed again but it does not help.

Do you have the same problem? Any ideas please. thanks

Comment: Does it happen when you run VS as an administrator ?

Comment: Yes...running as an administrator does not help either.